# How can I configure command-line options for a WSFC Service

Tags: failovercluster, windows-server-2022

I have a Windows Server 2022 Failover-Cluster consisting of two nodes. It has the Fileserver role configured (by wizard) which works as expected.

Using the Failovercluster-Manager (GUI), I added another resource of type *Generic Service* to that role. I selected the desired service and entered the desired command-line options as *Startup parameters* and confirmed by `Get-ClusterResource -Name myservice | Get-ClusterParameter`.

When I put the resource online (in GUI or PowerShell `Start-ClusterResource`), the service will start, but Task Manager reveals that the executable was started without command-line options.

How can I provide command-line options to this service?

Comment: Can you try with PowerShell to create the service, because I think you did it the proper way. If you need guidance with a PowerShell script let me then i can provide a example as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way I found is to edit the service definition in the Registry. Locate the Registry key of the service (by service name, not display name):

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\myservice
```

The value of `ImagePath` might be something like this:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\myservice.exe
```

Append the desired command-line options to `ImagePath`, like so:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\myservice.exe -a -bc --something -f "D:\somefolder\configfile"
```

Be sure to use only valid options and the correct format (`-f` vs. `/F`) expected by that executable. Invalid options or syntax will prevent the service from starting.

Do that **identically on all cluster nodes**, then stop and start the cluster resource.

PS: Adding that registry key to the registry replication keys of that cluster resource did not yield the desired result. It always reset `ImagePath` (removed the command-line arguments) before starting the service. But I may have done that in the wrong order.